# How to dissociate a static public IP+network interface from a VM in Azure?

Tags: azure, terraform, terraform-provider-azure

How to dissociate a static public IP/network interface or both of it from a VM and attach it to another VM using **terraform** in **MS Azure** just like an Elastic IP in AWS?

If azure terraform does not works, azure CLI is also feasible.

I was only able to find a way to detach an IP using azure CLI but could not be able to attach it to a new VM, due to an error - **NicInUse**.

```
 az network nic ip-config update \
 --name ipconfigmyVM \
 --resource-group myResourceGroup \
 --nic-name myVMVMNic \
 --remove PublicIpAddress
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After you detach a public Ip address as the above commands in your question, you can attach this disassociated Public Ip address to a new nic(without public Ip address). Due to the Nic conflicting error, you could verify if you are trying to attaching a public Ip address that is being in use with another NIC.

```
 az network nic ip-config update \
 --name ipconfigmyVM \
 --resource-group myResourceGroup \
 --nic-name myVMVMNic \
 --public-ip-address existingPublicIpAddress
```

[image]

Please note that the new public Ip address should have the same region as the NIc when you attach the new Public IP to the old Azure Nic. If the resources are not in the same resource group, you could use the resource ID of the Public IP address.

```
--public-ip-address "/subscriptions/xxx/resourceGroups/xxx/providers/Microsoft.Network/publicIPAddresses/test-pip"
```

With Terraform, you can associate Public IP Address with this NIC via using [public_ip_address_id](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/azurerm/r/network_interface.html#public_ip_address_id) in the `resource "azurerm_network_interface"`.

Comment: My requirement is to reuse same NIC+public IP from OLD VM and attach it to new VM. I dont think this is feasible in Azure.

Comment: In Azure, the NIC and public Ip are two separate resources. You can not reuse the same NIC directly but you can reuse the public IP address directly and easily. When you attach the NIC, it requires to stop VM first then attach that NIC.

Comment: Do you mean that I can directly attach a new VM form another VM with a static public IP without attaching NIC?

Comment: In fact, when you have a new deployed VM that must have a NIC but no need to have a public IP address. So you can just move the old Public Ip address to the new one.